# How to style a Tab using a custom class?

Tags: css

I have 5 tabs and would like to set a background color to only **Tab 4** using a custom class. Basically, I have a class called **"myClass"** and would like to use it in my css code.

to target the element (Tab 4)

Is there any way to use my class to target Tab 4?.

**Here's my working code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4MFpxG358l7tHRSQQIKi?p=preview)

Thanks a lot in advance!

**NOTE:**

- The **main idea** of using a custom class is so that I don't have to use nth-child(4).
- Using my custom class **+** the PrimeNG classes is what I'm looking for. I just don't want to use

  ```
  li:nth-child(4)
  ```

Comment: So you want to colur the last 4 only right.? so does it need to dynamic so that when you click on a child it will lose it color..?

Comment: @weBBer I only want to color Tab 4. If you look at my plunker you will see that its already done. I just want to update my css to use my custom class "myClass" to target Tab 4. Any ideas how to make that to happen?

Comment: So you just want to colour the tab that a user selects.?  Am I right.?

Comment: I don't care about other tabs. I just want to set a background color to Tab 4, that is all I want.

Comment: So you want to add `.myClass` dynamicalay to the 4th Tab.?? Is that you asking here.?

Comment: @weBBer yes that what I want. I would like to use .myClass and PrimeNg classes to target only Tab 4

Comment: use `[headerStyle]="{'background': 'red'}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/OYjprOc64lqkCRlqyYw4?p=preview

when you warp `headStyleClass` into brackets like this `[headStyleClass]` it will not added the class name

So you need to change it to `headerStyleClass="myClass"`

then in your css

```
.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav > li.ui-state-default.myClass {
   background: red !important;
}
```

**Solution Two**

you can make specific style inside your html code like this

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
       Content 1
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 4" [headerStyle]="{'background': 'red'}">
        Content 4
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 5">
        Content 5    
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/v6gJg2mZQKypRI4Cyt4C?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
.ui-tabview.ui-tabview-top > .ui-tabview-nav li.myClass {
    background: red !important;
}
```

this is your custom class `.myClass`

Comment: I just tried it and It doesn't seem to work. Can you share a plunker, please? Thanks

Comment: did you add custom class to your 4th tab ??

Comment: <p-tabPanel header="Header 4" headerStyleClass='myClass'>  like this ??

Comment: Thanks for the input bro!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plunker that works:

https://plnkr.co/edit/dzBtVCu2F32J6XGA2Fvi?p=preview

It just uses `.myClass { background-color: #f00 !important; }`

You basically had to adjust how the 4th tab was made to the following:

```
<p-tabPanel header="Header 4" headerStyleClass='myClass'>
```

Comment: I need to use [headerStyleClass] and NOT headerStyleClass, because I'll be binding a value. Can you update your css so it uses myClass and PrimeNG classes to target the element? Thanks

Comment: Apologies then, I'm unfamiliar with plunker, but the problem is that `headerStyleClass='myClass'` applies the class `myClass` to the tab, so it's then able to be used as a CSS Selector, but `[headerStyleClass] = 'myClass'` does not actually add it as a class or attribute to it.